# C# - Using the opened Pdf with Pdf reader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, itext

I am using

```
 axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(path);
```

to load a pdf inside a container now i have another function declared as public inside the same class and i am using itextsharp to read this i used

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader();
```

and nothing is passed inside the () how do i make sure that PdfReader makes use of opened Pdf only .

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no parameterless constructor in PdfReader class. You should supply it with a path to file, stream or bytes:

```
        const string pdfFilename = "/path/to/pdf/filename.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilename);
```

Comment: but since i have loaded the pdf in a container is it possible to read the same instead of specifiying the whole path

Comment: Could you please specify which (type?) container is the 'axAcroPDF1'? Maybe you can get bytes out of it?